# Pushing to git repository to GitHub doesn't work

Tags: git

I've made a SSH-Keygen in cmder and made repository in github to push the project to it, the files have been added correctly, and the commit worked too, but when I tried to push from origin to master it showed me a message:

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: Have you uploaded the public key to GitHub?

Comment: @choroba Yes I did it

Comment: Use ssh, *not Git*, to debug this. See the debug info in the GitHub help pages: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection

Comment: Also: I'm not sure exactly what `cmder` can do, but if it allows you to hopscotch from one machine to the next, you might want to set up an ssh agent. See the third linked duplicate.